# How do I estimate the value of a statistical distribution between certain intervals?

Tags: r

I am trying to find the values of a Gamma distribution between certain intervals. For instance, I'd be interested in the value of Gamma(1,1) in the interval 1 to 3.

I could use pgamma to get the value of Gamma(1,1) from 0 to a certain point. However, that doesn't help me with the above problem.

TLDR: I want the integral of a Gamma function between 1 and 3

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "the values of a Gamma distribution between ..."? Do you mean the integral of the probability (in which case see my answer below), or something else ... ?  Also, "is there an R function" is off-topic for Stack Overflow: please rephrase your question as "how do I calculate ..." ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the probability that a `Gamma(1,1)` random variable lies between 1 and 3 then `pgamma(3,1)-pgamma(1,1)` will do the trick, or more compactly `diff(pgamma(c(1,3),1))`. (This is the *integral* of the Gamma between these points.)

If you want something else (mean value? min and max?) then you'd have to compute `dgamma()` for a vector of points in that range, then compute the summary yourself.

Comment: Please see the edited question. Please let me know how I can improve the question more.

Comment: Seems fine. You don't need to say "based on comments/further clarification"; you can just edit your question to have it in whatever final form seems best